# EWS: Large mailbox - read state changes not syncing

Tags: android, client, exchange-server, synchronization, exchangewebservices

I've got a large mailbox being managed by a custom android Exchange EWS client.

Due to client constraints the mailbox is only syncing 100 messages at a time. In one test account there are over 10,000 messages.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when new messages arrive and they are marked as read in a browser based client, the read state change doesn't seem to be being sent to the Android client unless the mailbox has already been fully synced.

When the mailbox isn't fully synced, it doesn't seem to receive the "read state" changes until all the items from the mailbox are synced.

What's the best way to solve this problem? I'm thinking I have to sync all message headers to the android client. This may clear the sync queue, so the read state changes are ready to be received.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as I expected - I needed to sync all messages (just their headers) to the client. I discarded the messages that fell outside of my desired date range. Then the read state changes came through automatically.